# jScrollPane div shifts right on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jscrollpane

I was making final tweaks to a site and suddenly I realized that on Firefox the content in a jScrollPane is shifted totally to the right. It's fine on Safari, Chrome and IE9. I tried reversing everything I did, but nothing seems to affect the move.

Here's the URL: http://bdbcreative.com/index3.htm#web-design.htm

I'm totally stuck and would greatly appreciate any thoughts you might have.

Best - Joe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I figured it out. I needed to change the overflow:hidden CSS declaration that was being applied to the .panes class to overflow:inherit. I think this was necessary because of the way I structured the panes within the tabs - it probably won't be needed in a standard configuration.

To actually get it to work, I set up a CSS rule like this:
    .panes {
      overflow: inherit !important;
    }

The "!important" is necessary to override the JavaScript inline styling.

Hope this helps someone else.

Best - Joe